# How can one know which money exchanges happen in Ripple?

Tags: transactions, ripple, api, ripple-api

In Ripple, money can be exchanged in two ways:

- a payment is sent from a person to another person
- 2 satisfying offers fulfill each other

The [Ripple wiki](https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Format#OfferCreate_.287.29) states

> When an offer is placed it will immediately take any other offers that satisfy it.

Regular payments can be seen by the Ripple network by `Payment` transactions that are sent around. However, when two satisfying `OfferCreate` transactions occur, how can one know that they are being matched are will fulfill each other?

Also, for a `Payment` transaction, multiple possible "paths" can be defined. How do other nodes know which path is chosen and so which offers that the paths correspond to are fulfilled?

---

I'm currently monitoring the `payments` WebSocket stream, but I seem to need more than that to know what money exchanges happen in Ripple.

Comment: It's a lot more complex than I supposed it would be. Is there a script or explanation how you can determine all balance changes from a transaction? Also, I see a lot of `Payment` transactions that include the RippleState address `rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji` but I cannot make anything of these transactions.

Comment: That's "ACCOUNT_ONE", it's used in [RippleState](https://ripple.com/wiki/Ledger_Format#RippleState) ledger entries. I found looking at the JSON dumps of transactions (with a little input from the wiki) was all pretty easy to decipher.